# Multi Camera Support in Camera NDK API

Tags: android, camera, android-ndk, android-camera2, multi-camera-api

As we know android had introduced NDK API support for Camera2 and I was checking if it is possible to use [Multi-Camera API](https://developer.android.com/training/camera2/multi-camera) from NDK.

But nowhere I can find a sample implementation which makes use of Multi-camera using NDK APIs (if it exists)

At Java some  new constants, classes, and methods were added as part of Multi-Camera API support,  as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera2/multi-camera#multi) , but cant find something similar in NDK APIs.

Comment: Did you see: https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/camera#acamerametadata_islogicalmulticamera

Comment: Yes , I am ware of this API which helps to check if the camera is a logical camera and which also returns the physical Ids of the camera behind it. But what I am searching is sample code which makes use of new multicamera capabilities and helps to get multiple streams simultaneously.